# Swift show image from url in tableview cell

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, uitableview

I am getting data from api and I want to show this data in tableview cell.
I can show it but if there is a image link in it I can not show image. (Just showing text)

my data like: "blablablabla http://image.com/testImage"

I tried to split text and image but it is not a good solution.

How can I show data with image in swift?

Comment: check this out, https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it will help you.

Just download custom classes of Haneke from here

https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift

And use given code where you want

```
let URLString = self.items[indexPath.row]

let URL = NSURL(string:URLString)!

cell.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without third party code you can load an image into a `UIImageView` using the `imageWithData:` method. As you're using a `UITableView` you need to do this asynchronously so as not to impact scrolling performance. You can do this with GCD by placing your image loading code in a `dispatch_async` block.